# Set individual bit in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a 5 byte data element and I need some help in figuring out how in C++ to set an individual bit of one of these byte;  Please see my sample code below:

```
char m_TxBuf[4];
```

I would like to set bit 2 to high of byte `m_TxBuf[1]`.

```
    
00000 0 00
      ^ This one
```

Any support is greatly appreciated;
Thanks!

Comment: What? What does the 00** pattern mean? There are 14 digits in it, but you say you have 5 bytes of data (and you show a 4-byte array). And what do you mean by setting bit 2 to "high of byte m_TxBuf[1]"?

Comment: I believe he's just highlighting the bit he wants to set high.

Comment: Correct, just highlighting the bit to set, sorry for any confusion

Comment: and "high of byte" means? And why do you show a 4-byte array when you say you have 5 bytes of data?

Comment: it's not "high of byte", it's "bit 2 to high" "of byte m_TxBuf[1]".  "high" is a word used in low-level digital electronics to mean the "on" state of a bit/wire/bus/etc, which in this context means "set it to 1"

Comment: ooh, life would be a lot simpler if people used parentheses to eliminate ambiguity in english. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Bitwise operators in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators).

> "...set bit 2..."

[Bit endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering).

> `I would like to set bit 2 to high of byte m_TxBuf[1];`

`m_TxBuf[1] |= 1 << 2`

Answer (score 4):

You can use bitwise-or (`|`) to set individual bits, and bitwise-and (`&`) to clear them.

Answer (score 3):

```
m_TxBuf[1] |= 4;
```

To set a bit, you use bitwise or.  The above uses compound assignment, which means the left side is one of the inputs and the output.

Answer (score 3):

```
int bitPos = 2;  // bit position to set
m_TxBuf[1] |= (1 << bitPos);
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically we set bits using bitwise operator OR (operator| or operator|= as a shorthand).

Assuming 8-bits to a byte (where the MSB is considered the '7st' bit and the LSB considered the 0th: MSB 0) for simplicity:

```
char some_char = 0;
some_char |= 1 << 0; // set the 7th bit (least significant bit)
some_char |= 1 << 1; // set the 6th bit
some_char |= 1 << 2; // set the 5th bit
// etc.
```

We can write a simple function:

```
void set_bit(char& ch, unsigned int pos)
{
    ch |= 1 << pos;
}
```

We can likewise test bits using operator&.

```
// If the 5th bit is set...
if (some_char & 1 << 2)
    ...
```

You should also consider std::bitset for this purpose which will make your life easier.

Comment: When you mean the 8th bit, do you mean for the value of 1 or 128 (128-000000-1)

Comment: @JB_SO Apologies, I clarified that confusing part in the post. I'm going left to right from MSB (most significant bit) to LSB as we typically represent bits on paper. The MSB is the 1st bit, LSB 8th.

Comment: Setting the 8th bit, therefore, increases the value by 1.

Comment: I switched it to MSB 0 convention (ranging from 0 to 7) since '8th' bit really is confusing in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

Just use std::bitset<40> and then index bits directly.